# A phony target for sending a file via e-mail?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I would like to execute a command that takes a specific file in the project *(building it as necessary)* and sends it somewhere externally. For example, it may be a command that uploads a web page, or sends an e-mail. It may even write some additional files, such as a log, but that is not the point of calling it.

In other words, this action is evoked by naming its source, rather than the target — either because there is no tangible target, or it is insignificant and the action is primarily wanted for its side effect.

I see it that an extra command line argument will have to be provided, like this:

```
% BuildSystem send pizza.box
```

The command above should be equivalent to the following:

```
% BuildSystem pizza.box
% send pizza.box
```

Can *(and "should")* this be performed with the `shake` build system?

---

**P.S.** As [Daniel suggests in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55927732), I can extend `shake`'s argument parser. But I am not sure if this is the best practice for a case like this. It seems a little at odds with the way `shake` behaves, treating every single command line argument as a self-contained goal. It is also a whole new logic for the operator to design, so much overhead for such a menial task.

It might be more intuitive to request a `receipt` file for each `box` that is sent. For instance:

```
% BuildSystem pizza.receipt
```

— would then be equivalent to:

```
% BuildSystem pizza.box
% send pizza.box >pizza.receipt
```

On the downside, as I understand from [an official answer to a question nearby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55459477),we cannot have a pseudo-target like `pizza.send` that does not actually result in a file `pizza.send` being created. So I am not sure, again, if this is the right way.

**P.S. 2** It would be even better if we could replace the default *"file exists"* success verifier with a custom code. For instance, instead of verifying that a file `pizza.receipt` *(that we otherwise have no need for)* was indeed created, we may telephone the customer and ask them if they enjoyed the lunch. If we can arrange that, we can then invoke the corresponding rule with a *"pseudo-file"* target `pizza.send`. In general, build artifacts need not reside on the local file system at all, insofar as the code that can verify and retrieve them is given.

Comment: You can write whatever rules you want for Shake, replacing the success verifier with whatever suits you. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.17.8/docs/Development-Shake-Rule.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you want to send the email once, or repeatedly, even if `pizza.box` doesn't change. In both cases let's imagine you want to write `BuildSystem send.pizza.box` to cause the email to be sent.

**Send every time**

If you want to send a copy of `pizza.box` every time you can use a `phony` rule:

```
phony "send.pizza.box" $ do
    need ["pizza.box"]
    cmd_ "send-email" "pizza.box"
```

If you want that to work for all files, you can generalise to:

```
phonys $ \s -> case stripPrefix "send." s of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just file -> Just $ do
        need [file]
        cmd_ "send-email" [file]
```

**Send once**

If you only want one copy of each changed `pizza.box` to be sent then you need to record evidence of that locally, to stop sending successive copies. The easiest way to do that is actually create a file `send.pizza.box`:

```
"send.*" %> \out -> do
    let src = drop 5 out
    need [src]
    cmd_ "send-email" [src]
    writeFile' out ""
```

If you strongly want to avoid writing the `send.pizza.box` file you can use the `phony` technique from above combined with `addOracle` (but it's unlikely to be worth the additional hassle).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, shake supports this via [`phony`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.17.8/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:phony).

Comment: I get it that I can send a single hard-coded file, but I'm not sure how to select a file with a command line argument.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov I guess that's a fairly orthogonal question, no? Use whatever command-line parsing library you like, then `want` or `need` the appropriate thing.

Comment: I considered that `shake` deals with the command line arguments in its own way. I use it as `main = shakeArgs shakeOptions $ do stuff`. I thought maybe there is some functionality out of the box to handle a case like I described. Or some sort of best practice.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov `shakeArgsWith` lets you plug your own stuff into shake's command-line parsing; or `shakeOptDescrs` lets you plug shake's command-line stuff into your own parser.

Comment: Maybe you can move this advice into the body of your answer? In order for it to obtain permanence.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov You're asking a separate question. If you want to ask and answer that, do it as a separate question.